# My etherwallet.com password is overwritten by safari and only have partial private key

Tags: password

I only have the Keystore File (UTC / JSON) and can proof that the ETH sent to myetherwallet came from my poloniex account. 
I made a screenshot from the private key when I created the wallet, however later I found out that the complete private key is not displayed but just partially. I have like 30 from 60 characters in total fwiw.

Also the private key I copy/pasted once on my phone to get into the wallet. I have been calling around to Apple and what not to ask if its possible to get this old password back that has been overwritten by safari but everyone says this is impossible, same for the clipboard history.

Is there still hope for me?

How can I regain access to my account?

I really hope someone can help me out with this and that I made my story clear.

*new information*

I found the json number connected to this mew account on a screenshot, can this help me to regain access to my account?

Comment: I dont think its possible to get it back, sorry.

Comment: What is this new json number? How is it associated to your account?

Answer (score 1):

**Try brute forcing the password of the keystore file using hashcat**, see how to do it [in this answer to another similar question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74416/how-get-private-key-or-password-from-my-keystore) 
TL:DR If you still have the keystore file you could gain control over your wallet by using this approach. Additionally, the more information that you are able to recall (in regards to your password), the faster it will be to crack the password.

Answer (score 0):

The Keystore File should have all the data you need to gain access to your funds. However, if it was encrypted when it was downloaded, you'd also need the password used to encrypt it. So, head to [MyEtherWallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info), and select the "Keystore File" option. Walk through the steps it presents you with, and enter the password to decrypt it if prompted.

If that's successful, it will show you an interface with your address info and current funds, which you can back up properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I login with that keystore file on myetherwallet the only option it is giving me is to fill in my password which I don't have anymore.

Comment: If you don't have the password for the Keystore file, but you know generally what the password might be (did you pick something completely random, or did you pick some variation of a password you use commonly?), you might be able to brute-force the password for the Keystore file.

Comment: It is a completely random password generated by safari. Brute force this would take 39 years 

Comment: To restore using a Keystore file, you need the file itself and the password. To restore using the private key, you only need it, but you need all 64 characters. So, unfortunately, it sounds like you'd need to brute-force one or the other in order to get your funds back :(