# How get private key or password from my keystore

Tags: keystore, private

I had wallet from 2016, but i'm forget password login by keystore.
Current i just had keystore, how i can get private key or password keystore?

Thank so much

Comment: If you remember part of the password you can try pyethrecover to brute force possible passwords otherwise there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

**Try brute forcing the password of the keystore file using [hashcat.](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat)** 
1. Start by downloading a hashcat version compatible with your operative system. 
2. [Format your Ethereum keystore file into the required hashcat format](https://stealthsploit.com/2017/06/12/ethereum-wallet-cracking/) and save the hashcat format of your Ethereum keystore file as a .txt file (for illustrative purposes let's name it HFK.txt). 
3. Create another .txt file which contains any password fragments/keywords/parts that you recall/think could be found in the password, this is to increase the likelihood/speed of cracking the password associated with the keystore file (for illustrative purposes let's name it PSW.txt).
4. Specify the hashcode mode that you want to run, in your case it could be 15700 which specifies an ‘Ethereum SCRYPT’ mode. (run the hashcat --help command to find more details about the various modes). 
 
5. Choose which device you want to handle the brute forcing process (I highly recommend you to choose a device of type GPU over CPU) (run the hashcat -I command to find more details about your devices). 
6. Specify the rules of your password cracking attack. Rule/dictionary-based attacks are the most predominant ones when it comes to password cracking activities ([check this list for rules, note that the 'dive' rule is an efficient one!](https://www.notsosecure.com/one-rule-to-rule-them-all/)). 
7. Construct a command to forcefully run the brute forcing attack on the keystore file with the goal of recovering the lost password.

Finally, you should end up with something like this on Mac:
 `hashcat -m 15700 --force -D1 HFK.txt PSW.txt -w3 -r rules\dive.rule`

**HACK THE PLANET :)**